# What's the meaning of a Hubbard term determined by repeated investigation?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, band-structure, hubbard-model, bandgap

In the paper bellow they used GGA+U to investigate the structural, electronic and
optical properties of Ag- and Cu-doped ZnO.

https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/MI-05-2022-0088/full/html

They used a Hubbard term for Cu atom U=9.5eV as shown in the picture bellow. What do they mean by repeated investigation here? Can I use this value as a Hubbard term for Cu atoms in my calculations to improve the bandgap of my material.

[image]

Comment: I don't have access to that paper, but I suspect they just mean they tried different values. The Hubbard U values are not portable between implementations, so you'd have to use CASTEP and the same pseudopotentials as the authors. Personally, I don't trust these values anyway, the Cu value in particular looks very high. In any case, the Hubbard term is not really a method to correct the band-gap, that is just an occasional side-effect.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Was the comment by @PhilHasnip helpful? Are you able to provide more parts of the paper since Phil wasn't able to get access to it?